# How to call modal in php if not isset

Tags: php

> here is the problem i try to read some articles but it doesnt work

*I already included the java script in my php file it works when i trigger the modal using button but echoing it in php doesnt**

```
if(!isset($_SESSION ["id"])){
    echo "<script>$('#loginModal').modal('show')</script>"; }
```

**My modal**

```
   <div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

```
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try to put `if(!isset($_SESSION ["id"])){
    echo "<script>$('#loginModal').modal('show')</script>"; }` on the end of file

Comment: Make sure you're echoing it after the HTML with your modal and scripts in your document.

Comment: This will be a timing issue and a duplicate question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: You should wrap it into $('document').ready ... because you want to run your modal when page is loaded and dom is ready.

Comment: thanks for the help commended you both.

Comment: solve it already declared it in the end of the file